# If condition on list elements within list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to know whether it's possible to replace this:

```
results = [x for x in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == ".tif" and "abc" in os.path.splitext(x)[0]]
```

with something like:

```
results = [x for x in os.listdir(dir_path) if ext == ".tif" and "abc" in name for ext, name in os.path.splitext(x)]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What is `"abc" in name for ext, name in os.path.splitext(x)` suppose to mean? what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Do you mean: `[x for x in os.listdir(dir_path) if ext == ".tif" and "abc" in 
 os.path.splitext(x)[1]]` ???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes thanks, I meant the other way around. And "abc" is just an arbitrary name. I'm trying to list all the files which have "abc" in the filename and at the same time have extension ".tif"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `name` and `ext` using an inner generator expression:

```
results = [x for x, name, ext in ((x, *os.path.splitext(x)) for x in os.listdir(dir_path))
             if ext == ".tif" and "abc" in name]
```

Here, `*os.path.splitext(x)` unpacks the result of that call to the `name` and `ext` variables in the outer list comprehension (only in Python 3). For older versions, you can use `(x,) + os.path.splitext(x)` instead. Also note that `splitext` will return a tuple `(name, ext)`, not `(ext, name)`.

Alternatively, instead of using `splitext`, just check the filename directly, assuming that the part you want to find in the name part can not appear in the extension part of the file name.

```
results = [x for x in os.listdir(dir_path) if x.endswith(".tif") and "abc" in x]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your line is quite long, you might want to split it into multiple lines. You could wrap your condition in a function:

```
def filter_file(path):
    ext, name = os.path.splitext(path)
    if not ext == '.tif':
        return False
    return 'abc' in name
```

And then use

```
results = [x for x in os.listdir(dir_path) if filter_file(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that this is what you want:

```
results = [name + ext for name, ext in [os.path.splitext(x) for x in os.listdir(dir_path)] if ext == ".tif" and "abc" in name ]
```

Note: I have placed `name` before `ext`.

And the internal list is generating a list of tuples that is the name and ext value.